# Showing de Rham cohomology $H^1(S^n)$ is zero

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

I'm trying to find an elementary way to see that the 1st de Rham cohomology of the n-sphere is zero for $n>1$, $H^1(S^n) = 0$.

This is part of an attempt to find the de Rham cohomology of the n sphere generally. I have shown that $H^k(S^n) = H^{k-1}(S^{n-1})$ (for $k>1$) but to find the de Rham cohomology generally I need to show that $H^1(S^n) = 0$ and I am struggling to do this.

Is it possible to take a closed one form $\alpha$ on a sphere and explicitly find a function $f$ on $S^n$ that has $df = \alpha$, I've tried writing it out in coordinates and explicitly integrating but I haven't managed to get very far with this!

Comment: The Mayer-Vietoris sequence should be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I'm actually trying to do it without using the Mayer-Viertoris sequence if possible! That's what I was trying to refer to by "an elementary way" Thanks!

Comment: It's probably going to be hard to do this without working with two coordinate charts, which boils down to using a Mayer-Vietoris argument. And since the Mayer-Vietoris argument should produce a rather explicit formula for $f$ (as is done, for example, in the book of Bott and Tu), why not use it?

Comment: Also, didn't you already use Mayer-Vietoris to show that $H^k(S^n)=H^{k-1}(S^{n-1})$? Or did you have some other method to prove this?

Comment: I guess it is essentially a Mayer-Vietoris argument to show that $H^k(S^n) = H^{k-1}(S^{n-1})$ however this hasn't been explicitly introduced in my course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is $f(x)=\int_{\gamma_x} \alpha$ where $\gamma_x$ is a path from some chosen base point $x_0$ to $x$. But then for this to be well defined you have to say that all paths between $x$ and $x_0$ are homotopic, i.e. that your sphere is simply connected, so the whole argument gets a bit circular...

P.S. Traying to write things out in coordinates will not get you far because a closed form not being exact is a "global" thing, not a local one

Comment: I wouldn't say this is circular. Proving that $\pi_1(S^n)=0$ is independent from the pesky details of deRham cohomology, and boils down to the fact $S^n$ compactifies $n$-space.

Comment: To add on: It is not hard to see that the above function is zero of $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M),\Bbb R) = 0$, which indeed is the de Rham cohomology of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $S^n$ as the union of two open sets   $U= S^n-N$, $V=S^n-S $where $N,S$ are the north and south pole. Note that the intersection $U\cap V$ is connected if $n\geq 2$. $U,V$ are contracile (diffeomorphic to $R^,$, and on each of these sets the form $\alpha$ is exact and andmits primitive $f_U, f_V$. On the intersection $d(f_U-f_V)=0$ and by connexity $f_U-f_V$ must be a constant $c$. So $f_V=f_U+c$ one the intersection. As a primitive of $\alpha$ one can take $f_U$ on $U$ and $f_U +c$ on $V$. The main point is that the intersection is connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can imitate the argument that shows $\pi_1(S^n)=0$ if $n>1$ by removing  a point! Try it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is $\pi$ here though?